# Twig range with decimals

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to add a class "semi" to a star rating system I'm making with Twig. 
I can't create custom functions so it need to be done "frontend".

What I tried is this:

```
 {% for i in range(0, 5, 0.5) | limit(5) %} {# limit to 5 stars #}
  {% set starClass = (productScore >= i ? "on" : "off")  %}
   <span class="star fa fa-star {{ starClass }}"></span>
 {% endfor %}
```

When `productScore` equals 3 I get a result like:

```
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star off"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star off"></span>
```

But how can I create a function that also add a classname `semi` when `productScore` equals 3.5??

```
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star on"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star semi"></span>
 <span class="star fa fa-star off"></span>
```

Somebody have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this

```
{% set productScore = 3.5 %}
{% for i in range(0, 4) %}
    {% set starClass = productScore - i >= 1 ? 'on' : (productScore - i >= 0.5 ? 'semi' : 'off') %}
    <span class="star fa fa-star {{ starClass }}"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/du0buj)

Comment: That works perfectly. But why do you use in rang 0, 4? And not 0,5??

Comment: Because 0,1,2,3,4,5 are 6 stars?

Comment: Yes I'll take a coffee before asking stupid questions ;)